# How to make a base64 PDF file scale to fit the iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, embedding

I have the following code with an iframe which has base64 code of a PDF file as the source added by javascript.
This works perfectly on desktops however the pdf does not scale to fit when using on ios or android.
I have tried adding `#zoom=50` to the end of the src but it just throws a `Data URL Decoding Failed` error.

```
<iframe src='b64pdf....' width='100%' height='100%'></iframe>
```

Comment: Why do you have that as a base64? `<iframe src='yourPDF.pdf#view=FitH'></iframe>`

Comment: well, i use pdfmake to make dynamic pdf's on client side so they have to be base64